# MS Acess SQL - where clause to get year from date based on the year - data located in MS access form

Tags: sql, ms-access

OK, back again. I have a problem getting a drop down list to populate based on information in two fields.

I have got the SQL correct as to `Select` just one year if I put DateValue('01/01/2001') in both places, but I am trying now to get it to grab the year data from the MS access form - another drop down named "cboYear".

I'd hate to have to do something in VB, unless necessary.

so far I have gotten this to pull up something (its always incorrect)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Database_New.ASEC
FROM Database_New
WHERE Database_New.Date>=DateValue('01/01/' & [cboYear]) 
      And Database_New.Date<=DateValue('12/31/' & [cboYear]);
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT Database_New.ASEC
FROM Database_New
WHERE Database_New.Date>=DateValue('01/01/' + [cboYear]) 
      And Database_New.Date<=DateValue('12/31/' + [cboYear]);


SELECT DISTINCT Database_New.ASEC
FROM Database_New
WHERE Database_New.Date>=DateValue('01/01/' AND [cboYear]) 
     And Database_New.Date<=DateValue('12/31/' AND [cboYear]);
```

both give errors saying that it is too complex to compute.

Its probably something simple, but where do I go from here?

edit/addition

completely blanked out - yeah sorry about that

cboYear is not linked to anything, it just displays the distinct years avalible in the database, Ex - 2001, 2002, 2003 - just 4 digits.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly is the value of `[cboYear]`? As in, does the ComboBox Value property actually contain four digit numeric values?

Does this work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Database_New.ASEC
FROM Database_New
WHERE Year(Database_New.Date) = [cboYear];
```

Comment: no, added update to what I said - it only contains the 4 digits of the year.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you might try is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Database_New.ASEC
FROM Database_New
WHERE Database_New.Date>= DateSerial([cboYear], 1, 1) 
      And Database_New.Date<= DateSerial([cboYear], 12, 31);
```

Comment: Ok, this one "works" but I guess so does my first one with the & seperator. This appears to be an entirely different issue.

Messing around, I figured out that the issue lies in updating. Whenever I update and save the SQL query, the list updates and is correct. Change the value in the cboYear and the list in the ASEC box does not. 

Any ideas on how to get the thing to update?